# Spring: Does JdbcTemplate.query() with a RowCallbackHandler make concurrent calls to processRow()?

Tags: java, spring, concurrency

The Spring docs [specify](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/JdbcTemplate.html#query%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%5B%5D,%20org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowCallbackHandler%29) the `RowCallbackHandler` argument as an "object that will extract results, one row at a time". I see that `processRow()` is called once per row, but can these calls be concurrent?

I am having my `RowCallbackHandler` maintain state, including building a `Collection` of processed objects and occasionally submitting that Collection for further processing. I need to know if this `Collection` might be modified concurrently, or if I can trust that only one `processRow()` is happening at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is really up to you. If you've seen the source code, `RowCallbackHandler` you provide is wrapped in `RowCallbackHandlerResultSetExtractor` adapter class and then wrapped again in `QueryStatementCallback` (sic!).

Never mind, the point is: if you pass the same `RowCallbackHandler` instance to two concurrent `query()` executions, Spring will use the same object through all this layers. But if you create new instance of `RowCallbackHandler` per every `query()` execution, you are safe.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question, it's 1 row at a time.  The example code is from their result set extractor which calls this interface.

```
while (rs.next()) {
   this.rch.processRow(rs);
}
```